# Error encountered when using DrissionPage and multi-threading: AttributeError: 'Browser' object has no attribute '_driver'

Tags: python

### Description

I encountered an error while using the `DrissionPage` library for web automation in a multi-threaded environment. When attempting concurrent access to Baidu for search operations, the program threw an `AttributeError: 'Browser' object has no attribute '_driver'`.

### Steps to Reproduce

Below is the code I used to replicate this problem:

```py
from DrissionPage import ChromiumPage, ChromiumOptions
import threading

search_data = ["1", "2", "3"]

def search(data):
    options = ChromiumOptions().auto_port()
    page = ChromiumPage(addr_or_opts=options)
    page.get('https://www.baidu.com/')
    page.ele('#kw').input(data)
    page.ele('#su').click()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    threads = []
    for data in search_data:
        t = threading.Thread(target=search, args=(data,))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```

### Expected Behavior

I expected each thread to open a browser window, access Baidu, and perform a search.

### Actual Behavior

The program threw the following error:

```bash
Exception in thread Thread-3 (search):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PATH\PYTHON310\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "D:\PATH\PYTHON310\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\Code\PycharmProjects\AutoTestCraft\DPThread4.py", line 9, in search
    page = ChromiumPage(addr_or_opts=options)
  File "D:\Code\PycharmProjects\AutoTestCraft\.venv\lib\site-packages\DrissionPage\_pages\chromium_page.py", line 34, in __init__
    super().__init__(address, tab_id)
  File "D:\Code\PycharmProjects\AutoTestCraft\.venv\lib\site-packages\DrissionPage\_pages\chromium_base.py", line 67, in __init__
    self._connect_browser(tab_id)
  File "D:\Code\PycharmProjects\AutoTestCraft\.venv\lib\site-packages\DrissionPage\_pages\chromium_base.py", line 90, in _connect_browser
    tabs = self.browser.driver.get(f'http://{self.address}/json').json()
  File "D:\Code\PycharmProjects\AutoTestCraft\.venv\lib\site-packages\DrissionPage\_base\browser.py", line 98, in driver
Exception in thread Thread-2 (search):
    return self._driverTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PATH\PYTHON310\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner

AttributeError: 'Browser' object has no attribute '_driver'. Did you mean: 'driver'?
    self.run()
  File "D:\PATH\PYTHON310\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\Code\PycharmProjects\AutoTestCraft\DPThread4.py", line 9, in search
    page = ChromiumPage(addr_or_opts=options)
  File "D:\Code\PycharmProjects\AutoTestCraft\.venv\lib\site-packages\DrissionPage\_pages\chromium_page.py", line 34, in __init__
    super().__init__(address, tab_id)
  File "D:\Code\PycharmProjects\AutoTestCraft\.venv\lib\site-packages\DrissionPage\_pages\chromium_base.py", line 67, in __init__
    self._connect_browser(tab_id)
  File "D:\Code\PycharmProjects\AutoTestCraft\.venv\lib\site-packages\DrissionPage\_pages\chromium_base.py", line 90, in _connect_browser
    tabs = self.browser.driver.get(f'http://{self.address}/json').json()
  File "D:\Code\PycharmProjects\AutoTestCraft\.venv\lib\site-packages\DrissionPage\_base\browser.py", line 98, in driver
    return self._driver
AttributeError: 'Browser' object has no attribute '_driver'. Did you mean: 'driver'?
```

### Environment

`Python Version: 3.10`

`DrissionPage Version: 4.0.0b16`